# Add Azure AD groups into SharePoint Online site member’s group Programmatically(C#)

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

I need to programmatically  add Azure AD groups into SharePoint Online site member’s group. What property of AAD group is required for this?

I am not getting any sample example related to this.

Quick response is much needed.

Comment: Do you want to add an AzureAD Group as a member of a SPO site?

Comment: Yes, I want to add Azure AD group into Site' member group

Comment: A group instead of a user then. What type of SPO site? Or any of them?